# Can't alphabetize(sort) strings?

Tags: c, string, sorting, insertion-sort

So I'm using insertion sort to sort the strings.
It runs if the strings are already are sorted. If they are partially sorted or completely reversed. It either runs producing incorrect results or gives error:`(0xC0000005)`.

Declaration of ptr: `char **ptr;` where memory is dynamically allocated.

Insertion sort:

```
 void insertionSort(char **ptr,int rows,int cols)
{
   char *key;
   int i,j;

   //first element is considered sorted 

   for( i=1;i<=rows-1;i++)
   {
      key=ptr[i];
      for( j=i-1;strcmp(key,ptr[j])<0 && j>=0;j--)
      {
         ptr[j+1]=ptr[j];
      }
      /*Program sometimes stalls at this part and gives error:`(0xC0000005)` 
      when strings are partially sorted/completely reversed*/
      ptr[j + 1] = key;
   }
}
```

It is your pretty standard insertion sort implmentation. Works with numbers so I don't know why I can't sort the strings.

Also this is how `ptr`'s values were defined from the user:

```
void read_charArray(char **ptr,int rows,int cols)
{
   for(int i=0;i<=rows-1;i++)
   {
      printf("Enter name for name #%-3d: ",i+1);
      fgets(ptr[i],cols+5,stdin);
      ptr[i]=strtok(array[i],"\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: Please make a [mre] to demonstrate what you describe.

Comment: Just a little side hint, people here like code to b readable without scrolling horizontally, especially if the code also needs vertical scrolling; which yours will when you made a proper MRE.

Comment: How do you define array passed to that function?

Comment: @Yunnosch Is this alright?

Comment: @DenisSheremet Just edited it

Comment: Still no definition of array. I mean, inside your `main` you've probably have something like `char array[X][Y]`, I'd like to see that part too

Comment: It could be important, because as far as I remember `char array[X][Y]` is an array of const pointers to `char*` thus modifying it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @DenisSheremet Is this good?

Comment: Well, it's enough to prove my assumption wrong. Not enough to tell why your program fails though. Try using debugger.

Comment: No this does not match the idea of a [mre]. Please follow the link and [edit] your question to provide one as described there.

Comment: @Yunnosch Apparently, I still need to wait a day to accept the answer since I answered the question

Comment: Oops, my mistake. I missed that you answered yourself. Which is fine.

Comment: @Yunnosch    All good

Answer (score 2):

The error lies in the 2nd `for()` loop of the insertion part of the program:

Insertion sort:

```
 void insertionSort(char **ptr,int rows,int cols)
{
   char *key;
   int i,j;

   //first element is considered sorted 

   for( i=1;i<=rows-1;i++)
   {
      key=ptr[i];
      for( j=i-1;strcmp(key,ptr[j])<0 && j>=0;j--)
      {
         ptr[j+1]=ptr[j];
      }
      /*Program sometimes stalls at this part and gives error:`(0xC0000005)` 
      when strings are partially sorted/completely reversed*/
      ptr[j + 1] = key;
   }
}
```

When `j` is decremented to be below 0, program actually **continues** to evaluate `strcmp(key,ptr[j])` **first** despite the `j>=0` expression being present(basically *short-circuiting*. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/201899 )-->This means that you are trying to access memory that is out of bounds(not allocated for program) thus causing an error:`(0xC0000005)`.

This error: `(0xC0000005)` means "**you accessed memory you had no right to use**", such as, abusing pointers or arrays that aren't big enough,etc.

To rectify this all you have to do is switch up the condition expressions in `for( j=i-1; strcmp(key,ptr[j])<0  && j>=0;j--)` to `for( j=i-1; j>=0 && strcmp(key,ptr[j])<0;j--)`.

What this does is that the moment `j` is decremented to be below 0, program tests for `j>=0` **first** thus exiting loop rather than causing an error.

Comment: Good job getting it solved. Always keep in mind as your data sets grow, simple sorts become increasingly inefficient, e.g. [Time Comparison of Quick Sort, Insertion Sort and Bubble Sort](https://vinayakgarg.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/time-comparison-of-quick-sort-insertion-sort-and-bubble-sort/). Other sorts like the bottom_up merge-sort and quicksort (divide and conqueror algorithms) out perform bubble and insertion sorts by orders-of-magnitude.

Comment: Can we then just use merge sort for *most* cases seeing that it seems to be the most efficient?

Comment: Yes, but make sure you are using the *Bottom_Up Iterative* merge-sort instead of the *Top_Down* purely recursive merge-sort or for large data sets, you will exhaust the stack space due to the recursive function calls. [Merge sort - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) provides a good explanation of both algorithms.

Comment: Is there a reason why the *iterative/recursive* is called *Bottom_Up/Top_Down* respectively? PS: When it comes to algorithms, do you understand the general concepts encompassing the algorithm and just copy&paste the template of algorithm?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Any particular reason or just your preference?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `j` is always initialized to `i-1` so `ptr[j+1]` executes as `ptr[rows-1]`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: My reading error as I read the non-idiomatic `for( i=1;i<=rows-1;i++)` as `for( i=1;i<=rows;i++)`.  Consider 1) `for( i=1;i<rows;i++)` as it is C idiomatic and simpler to read.  2) a [MCVE] is helpful - it encourages Up votes too.

Comment: Completely agree that idiomatic=simpler to read. Just that for this particular idiom, I personally prefer `i<=rows-1` than `i<rows`. I will try sticking to idiomatic formats for other aspects. Thanks for the reminder.